# How to have seperator line for menu icons also in ion list?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

[image]

I want to have the list seperator line that i have marked in the above image under my icons also like in the second image.

[image]

Here is my code for the ionic list:

app.html:

```
<ion-list >

  <button  class="menu-text" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" class="icon-color" item-left> </ion-icon> 
    {{ p.title }}
  </button>


</ion-list>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 this.pages = [
  { title: 'My Profile', component: MyprofilePage , icon: 'md-person'},
  { title: 'My Goals', component: MygoalsPage, icon: 'md-flag' }, 

];
```

app.scss:

```
 .icon-color{
    color:#8ad5ef;
    font-size: 1px; 

}

.menu-text{
    color:#8ad5ef;
    font-size: .9em; 
}
```

What should i do to get the desired effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<ion-list>
  <button no-padding ion-item icon-right *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" class="icon-color"> </ion-icon> 
    {{ p.title }}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-u4fcy5?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)